# Why does CGBitmapContextCreate expect double the number of bytesPerRow?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to generate a pixel buffer using a bitmap context on iOS (in ObjC). The abridged code (to remove null checks etc) is below.

```objectivec
CGFloat width = 1;
CGFloat height = 1;

CVPixelBufferRef buffer;
CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                      width, 
                                      height,  
                                      kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8,
                                      nil, 
                                      &buffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
void *data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer);

CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, 
                                         width, 
                                         height, 
                                         8, 
                                         0, 
                                         space, 
                                         (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

// ... draw into context

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
```

This is trying to create a bitmap context *for a single pixel*, where both the input and the output pixels are 8-bit grayscale.

I get the following output (I added the bold):

> CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be **at least 2** for 8 integer bits/component, 1 components, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast.

Why does it double the expected bytes per row? This is consistent for the width / height combinations I've tried, and 'works' if I halve the width parameter in `CGBitmapContextCreate`. Note also that if I pass in a value for `bytesPerRow` then it still fails this check and gives the same output.

Am I missing something obvious?

*Edit: formatting.*

Answer (score 0):

`kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast` was wrong. I needed to use `kCGImageAlphaNone`.

The bitmap create call now looks like:

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, 
                                         width,
                                         height, 
                                         8,
                                         CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer),
                                         space, 
                                         kCGImageAlphaNone);
```